# How is an empty string stored in a char array?

Tags: c, string

If I have an array declared as

```
char arr[1] = "";
```

What is actually stored in memory? What will a[0] be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C-strings are zero-terminated. Thus, `"abc"` is represented as `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 }`.

Empty strings thus just have the zero.

This is also the reason why a string must always be allocated to be one `char` larger than the maximum possible length.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are null-terminated. An empty string contains one element, the null-terminator itself, i.e, `'\0'`.

```
char arr[1] = "";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char arr[1] = {'\0'};
```

You can imagine how it's stored in the memory from this.

Answer (score 2):

`a[0]` is the null character, which can be referred to as `'\0'` or `0`.

A string is, by definition, "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character". For an empty string, the terminating null character is the first one (at index 0).

Answer (score 2):

`arr[0] = 0x00;`

however, if you did not assign any value like

`char arr[1];`

then `arr[0] = garbage value`

Answer (score 2):

It will pique more if the array is declared as `char arr[] = "";`

In this case the `sizeof(arr) is 1 and strlen(arr) is 0` .

But still self analysis can be done by adding print like this `printf("%d", arr[0]);` So that you can understand by yourself.

string is a sequence of characters, in your case there is no character is present inside "". So it stores only `'\0'` character in `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

C string is end with NULL, so the empty string "" actually is "\0", Compiler help do this,
so strlen("") equal 0 but sizeof("") equal to 1.

Comment: So arr[1] is out of range.